# Do +1 weapons add their bonus to attack, damage, or both?

Tags: magic-items, dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

Self-explanatory. I've combed through the DCC core rulebook but I couldn't find a clarification on what a magic weapon's bonus actually applies to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Both attack and damage.

From **The Attack Roll** (page 78):

> He also adds any bonuses from spells, magic items, or class abilities (such as a thief’s backstab ability).

From **Damage and Death** (page 93):

> If the attack was made with a melee weapon, add the attacker’s Strength bonus. Add other bonuses due to spells, magic items, or class abilities.

Both citations from the 5th printing of DCC.